# I got problems with HLISA drag and drop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha, undetected-chromedriver

I'm using HLISA and undetected_chrome for captcha cracker bot but drag_and_drop function doesn't work or I don't actually know what is the problem here:

```
stat = self.custom_selector(400, "//iframe[@id='tcaptcha_iframe_dy']", "switch_frame")

if not stat:
    return False

stat = self.custom_selector(600, "//div[@id='slideBg']", "get_attribute")
if not stat:
    return False
else:
    url = stat.split("background-image: url(")[1].split(")")[0].replace('"', '')

img = self.download_image(url)
if img:
    dis = self.process_image(img)
    if not dis:
        return False
else:
    print("not img")
    return False

cap_element = self.custom_selector(300, "//div[@class='tc-fg-item tc-slider-normal']")
if not cap_element:
    return False

action = HLISA_ActionChains(self.driver)
dragDrop = action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(cap_element, int(dis), 0)
dragDrop.perform()  # I'm having problem here
```

I tried to debug by looking at HLISA function something but I don't know what is the problem.